# ntfs D: Partition windows 7

Tags: windows, ntfs

I have similar problem, I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on top of Windows 7, I have all my files on a logical partition `D:` couldn't access that partition from Ubuntu. During installation I choose to encrypt the hard drive.

How do I get my `D:` files on Windows previously?

Here are some useful information about my system:

### blkid

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="fc91920a-ede7-43fb-a23a-17fb4c1537b0" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="6a5f9794-a72a-4c6c-bac0-66222cf38934" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" 
/dev/mapper/sda5_crypt: UUID="AUw1wk-YEAG-v5Wz-PHIJ-B2vQ-1eAx-08fh2L" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root: UUID="9e03b2aa-2dfe-4b76-84f1-b8428272af21" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="b778a1db-839f-45ef-9ee6-a9877b6054f4" TYPE="swap"
```

### fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e65a7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   976771071   488134657    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   976771071   488134656   83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt: 499.8 GB, 499847790592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60769 cylinders, total 976265216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2c677a96

                 Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root: 495.6 GB, 495649292288 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60259 cylinders, total 968065024 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x95cabf50

                  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1: 4143 MB, 4143972352 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 503 cylinders, total 8093696 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4ca7eb06

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 4143 MB, 4143972352 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 503 cylinders, total 8093696 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xadfe8bcb

                  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

### ls -la /dev/mapper/

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     140 Jan 30 12:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root    4400 Jan 30 12:35 ..
crw-------  1 root root 10, 236 Jan 29 16:16 control
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Jan 30 11:46 cryptswap1 -> ../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Jan 30 12:02 sda5_crypt -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Jan 30 11:46 ubuntu-root -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Jan 30 11:46 ubuntu-swap_1 -> ../dm-2
```

### lvmdiskscan

```
/dev/ram0              [      64.00 MiB] 
/dev/mapper/sda5_crypt [     465.52 GiB] LVM physical volume
/dev/ram1              [      64.00 MiB] 
/dev/sda1              [     243.00 MiB] 
/dev/ubuntu/root       [     461.61 GiB] 
/dev/ram2              [      64.00 MiB] 
/dev/ubuntu/swap_1     [       3.86 GiB] 
/dev/ram3              [      64.00 MiB] 
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 [       3.86 GiB] 
/dev/ram4              [      64.00 MiB] 
/dev/ram5              [      64.00 MiB] 
/dev/sda5              [     465.52 GiB] 
/dev/ram6              [      64.00 MiB] 
/dev/ram7              [      64.00 MiB] 
/dev/ram8              [      64.00 MiB] 
/dev/ram9              [      64.00 MiB] 
/dev/ram10             [      64.00 MiB] 
/dev/ram11             [      64.00 MiB] 
/dev/ram12             [      64.00 MiB] 
/dev/ram13             [      64.00 MiB] 
/dev/ram14             [      64.00 MiB] 
/dev/ram15             [      64.00 MiB] 
1 disk
20 partitions
1 LVM physical volume whole disk
0 LVM physical volumes
```

### pvscan

```
PV /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt   VG ubuntu   lvm2 [465.52 GiB / 48.00 MiB free]
Total: 1 [465.52 GiB] / in use: 1 [465.52 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You say that you have a _"similar problem"_. But similar to what?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might have chosen to erase the entire disk when you installed Ubuntu, not just the `C:\` partition (if you're positive `D:\` wasn't a separate disk, though it really should have been displayed then).

If the data hasn't yet been overwritten, you can try to recover some of it.

See these for details:

- [NTFS recovery software for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49497/ntfs-recovery-software-for-ubuntu)
- [How to recover lost partitions data?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106306/how-to-recover-lost-partitions-data)
- [How to recover a deleted NTFS partition with data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171163/how-to-recover-a-deleted-ntfs-partition-with-data)
- [How to recover data from NTFS partition that was made into a Swap partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98790/how-to-recover-data-from-ntfs-partition-that-was-made-into-a-swap-partition)

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a problem where I could access my NTFS drive before, but then suddenly I couldn't access it any longer. It turned out that if the windows system is put in suspend mode instead of shutting down, then I can't access the NTFS drive, so just logging into windows and shutting it down made it available in Ubuntu again. Perhaps you can try this?

Comment: I no longer have windows installed, I got red of it.