# DATA RECOVERY from a NTFS formatted disk

Tags: data-recovery

While installing Ubuntu, by mistake I gave my C drive as the Swap space. It ended up formatting the logical drive(E, but not C !). I realised my mistake in the middle and forcefully ended installation. However it formatted the disk. On windows, the disk space appears to be unallocated. Is there a way I can recover the data?

Comment: you might find this helpful too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu

Comment: see also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Answer (score 0):

You gave it as swap?! And you're currently using this Linux? I think you lost all your files. Disable this swap space immediately (`swapoff`). The longer it remains active the less chance you have of saving anything. If you can keep this PC off, it's better.

I suggest you boot your computer with [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/). It has a number of tools for maintenance... among these, there are a few for recovering deleted files/files from lost partitions.

Good luck. If your computer has sufficient RAM, maybe Linux hasn't used your swap partition yet and you may have a chance of recovering your important files.

Comment: I realised my mistake in the middle and forcefully ended installation. However it formatted the disk. On windows, the disk space appears to be unallocated. Do you think the softwares like TestDisk can recover the data? (It was NTFS). Thank you :)

Comment: I don't remember the names of any specific applications I've used in similar situations. But you can find a number of them in the Boot CD I suggested. There are also a few Linux tools you can use if you prefer to boot to a live CD. But it's important to keep your swap off as soon as you boot. But since you have probably not used this swap partition, I believe your chances are good.

Comment: Check the links in comments for your question. They seem to give better answers.

Comment: (http://askubuntu.com/questions/98790/how-to-recover-data-from-ntfs-partition-that-was-made-into-a-swap-partition) has the answers. Thank you very much.